# How to get data returned from Ajax appended to a div? -- JQuery + Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get data returned from a controller and append it to a div. Here is the code I have:

```
$(this).parent().find('list').append(__WHAT_GOES_HERE?__);
```

**How should I get data to append using ajax in JQuery?** I know this is a very basic question -- I'm new to JS :(

PS. Lets assume the controller's path is `/ajax_get_items`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to load it into a class, so `list` would be `.list`

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_get_items",
    type : "POST",
    data : { // If you need data to be posted
        id : 12,
        num : "test"
    },
    success : function(result){
        $(this).parent().find('.list').append(result);
        // If a JSON object is returned, use the following line:
        // $(this).parent().find('.list').append(result.html);

    }
})
```

Or if you want to just load data without params (GET method):

```
$(this).parent().find('.list').load("/ajax_get_items");
```

If you want more information about ruby rails and jQuery:  http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/02/24/jquery-rails-and-ajax

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax_get_items',
    success: function(data) {
    $('#selector').parent().find('list').append(data)
}
});
```

Note that you can't use 'this' in this context depending on where this call is made, or you might end up with unexpected results

Comment: Your solution expects data is in the correct HTML markup, which is hardly what you get from your backend system. That has to be done in the frontend with JS.

Comment: Thats what the OP asked about, and in rails that's not what you hardly get, its pretty easy to get valid html. If any manipulation is needed, or JSON objects assumed, the data can still be manipulated inside the function

Comment: True. You can get JSON returned, but still it not html. And it doesn't make sense to return html from the controller. It should only return data in some standard notation, viz JSON. But it is the onus of the consumer of the data to format it as per its need. That is how separation of terms can truly be achieved, so that you can use the same function in other places returning only data and not the formatted html, which the new caller might not have asked for

Comment: One example of very common case of controller returning html is graceful degradation of modal dialogs.

You can return via ajax the same div that would otherwise be displayed inside the normal layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('somelink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax(url, data, success:function(resData) {
    resultSet = resData.extract(resData);
  }
}
```

Basically this part handles the response from the ajax call and `extract` is supposed to build up your required html from the returned data.

After this you can simply say

`$(this).parent().find('list').append(resultSet);`

But this assumes the major work is done in the function `extract` with the returned data.
There you build up your list (or whatever) html is needed.